# Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH. Is 'node' installed?

Tags: node.js

I tried to run my discord.js code and the came an [Pop-Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwHjk.png) after I killed the node process in the task manager

Here is my launch.json file code:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Bot/main.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try editing the launch.json file code to include your NodeJS path:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Bot/main.js",
            "runtimeExecutable": "---YOUR NODE JS PATH---"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, for this kind of issue simply restarting the system might work.